# Solving a recursion issue

Tags: python

Hi I've been trying to figure out how to manipulate a string like the following example.

I have a string that looks like this.

```
aa_bb_cc_dd
```

and from that I want.

```
aa/aa_bb/aa_bb_cc/aa_bb_cc_dd
```

I need this to be recursive and that's where I'm having troubles.
Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
a = "aa_bb_cc_dd"

# split the string on `_`
x = a.split("_")

op = ""
for i in range(len(x)):
  op = op + "_".join(x[:i+1])+"/"

print(op.strip("/"))
```

Output:

```
aa/aa_bb/aa_bb_cc/aa_bb_cc_dd
```

Comment: This isn't a recursive solution, though.

Comment: Yes I see that I thought I needed it to be but I guess not.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai using recursion here might be overkill

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Agreed, but the question says "I need this to be recursive", which led me to believe that it was a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive solution as asked:

```
def recursive_fn(s, start_idx):
    if start_idx >= len(s):
        return ''
    return s[:start_idx+2] + '/' + recursive_fn(s, start_idx + 3)

result = recursive_fn('aa_bb_cc_dd', 0)[:-1]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple List Comp, Try this

```
inp_str = "aa_bb_cc_dd"
inp_list = inp_str.split("_")
print '/'.join(['_'.join(inp_list[:i]) for i in range(1,len(inp_list)+1)])

Results: aa/aa_bb/aa_bb_cc/aa_bb_cc_dd
```

Hope this helps U :)